# file not load from browser cache with expires and cache control

Tags: gwt, apache2, browser-cache, mod-expires, mod-headers

I'm working on a gwt project and i set a proxy with apache2, mod_proxy, mod_expires and mod_headers to manage loadbalancing and cache.

All resources, are fine exept one XXX.cache.html. With Firefox/Firebug or chrome/developer Tools, i can see that it's the only file which is not "from cache". And it's the biggest file

The html file (generated by gwt compiler) does not contains meta with cache parameters.

I don't see what is wrong :

Request:

```
HeadersPreviewResponseCookiesTiming
Request URL:https://myproject.visionobjects.com//com.visionobjects.myscript.myProject/75797371ADDF8643260E34AC670CE051.cache.html
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=215925392.462910615.1307714119.1324051842.1332755699.3; MYSCRIPTWSSESSONID=myproject-node1ali0jv5kfn371vbphmbhekcx9.myproject-node1; __utma=255591828.1472483096.1335971537.1348212480.1349343132.10; __utmb=255591828.15.10.1349343132; __utmc=255591828; __utmz=255591828.1335971537.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:myproject.visionobjects.com
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1284.2 Safari/537.13
```

Response:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=31536000, public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 04 Oct 2012 10:12:43 GMT
Expires:Fri, 04 Oct 2013 10:12:43 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=98
Server:Jetty(7.6.5.v20120716)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: How are you testing? F5/Ctrl+R? or following a link from another page? (or a bookmark)

Answer (score 0):

The request has `Cache-Control: max-age=0` and `Pragma: no-cache`, so it's not about your server configuration.